# selenium-how can I use element of same page after driver.back()

Tags: selenium

I want to reuse the same page

by `driver.back()` or any possible way

```
sample_xpath='f'/html/body/form/div/div[{k}]'
sample_element=driver.find_element_by_xpath(sample_xpath)
.
.
.
driver.back()
sample_element=driver.find_element_by_xpath(sample_xpath)
```

but after driver.back()
I got no such element error

what should I do?

Comment: Is the element for sure present in the DOM after back navigation? The error 'no such element' is not without a reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reload the page once you perfrom

```
driver.back()
driver.refresh()
time.sleep(5)
sample_element=driver.find_element_by_xpath(sample_xpath)
```

also instead of

```
driver.back()
```

try to use

```
driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
```

Comment: it doesn't work.
it is a dynamic web so If I refresh it, It goes back first view

Comment: so use this javascript injector `driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")` ,also what do you mean by it's a dynamic web page ? JS should work, it does not matter if webpage is static or dynamic/.